# Universal quantifier and "such that"

Tags: logic, notation, quantifiers

I'm given the following predicate that I'm trying to understand from a course example.

$\forall n \in\mathbb N : n^2 \ge n$

is the colon for such that correct?

I understand that it reads as "for all elements in the natural set such that the square of n is greater or equal to n"

Should it be $\forall n \in\mathbb N, n^2 \ge n$? "for all elements in the natural set the square of $n$ is greater or equal to $n$"

it makes more sense to me this way. But I'm not sure if my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always, you should defer to your professor on matters of convention. If he says to use a colon in such and such way, do it. That being said...

Usually you see a colon in set builder notation, ie $$\{n\in\mathbb{N} : n^2 \geq n\}$$ In which case you would read it as "(the set containing) all natural numbers *such that* $n$ squared is greater than or equal to $n$."

The colon is usually *not* used in propositions meant to be read, so you wouldn't use $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:n^2≥n$$ to mean "for all elements in the natural set such that the square of n is greater or equal to n... (insert rest of proposition)."

You *can* simply use a comma to mean "such that," but generally it makes your math much less understandable. For instance, "$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n^2 \geq n$" could mean "...for all $n$ such that $n^2 \geq n$" or it could mean "Each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ has the property that $n^2 \geq n$"

Shorthand should never sacrifice clarity, so I would recommend "$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n^2 \geq n$..." Basically,

1. Follow appropriate conventions
2. Never sacrifice clarity for conciseness.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The punctuation in the examples \begin{gather}\forall n{\in}\mathbb{N}:n^2≥n\tag1\\\exists n{\in}\mathbb{N},\,n^2≥n\tag2\\\exists n {\in}\mathbb N:n^2 \ge n\\\forall n {\in}\mathbb N,\, n^2 \ge n\end{gather} are superfluous, primarily to supply typographical breathing space. In $(1)$ and $(2)$ in particular, the punctuation can be confusing (and break the flow of reading), as evidenced by your Question. In $(1),$ the colon is not to be read as "such that" (doing so renders the statement ungrammatical and incoherent); in $(2),$ the comma is similarly neither literal nor to be understood as a pause.

In more complex formalisations, to delimit quantifier scope, commas/colons/periods are sometimes used in place of parentheses. Because **this usage of punctuation conflicts with the above, punctuating quantifiers potentially creates ambiguity and even misinterpretation**.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4518680/21813)'s an example where adding commas creates confusion and ambiguity.