# Quantifiers for multiple variables?

Tags: quantifiers

I know about the universal quantifier(translated to "for all") $\forall$ and the existential quantifier(there exists) $\exists$. But I am not sure what the correct way is to use them for multiple multiple variables.

For example:

1. How would you use the quantifiers to express "for all x, y, c..."?
2. How would you use the quantifiers to express "for all x, y, c in $\mathbb{R}$..."?
3. How would you use the quantifiers to express "for all x, y, c in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a, b such that..."?

Comment: $\forall x\forall y\forall c$, or $\forall x,y,c$ for short

Answer (score 2):

Both

1. $\forall x,y,c \dots$
2. $\forall x,y,c \in \mathbb R \dots$
3. $\forall x,y,c \in \mathbb R: \exists a, b: \dots$

and

1. $\forall x, \forall y, \forall c \dots$
2. $\forall x \in \mathbb R, \forall y \in \mathbb R, \forall c \in \mathbb R \dots$
3. $\forall x \in \mathbb R, \forall y \in \mathbb R, \forall c \in \mathbb R: \exists a, \exists b: \dots$

are acceptable.

Comment: Ahh thanks! But why would you use a colon to separate the "for all" and "there exists" parts instead of a comma? Any specific reason?

Comment: I didn't want $\mathbb R$ sticking to $\exists$. I have seen people use a comma ",", or bracket all the universal quantifier "phrases" (e.g. $(\forall x)(\exists y)$). It kinda means "such that".

Comment: Just to point out that these colons/commas/periods inserted after $\forall x$ and $\exists x$ are unnecessary at best, and, frequently, [gives rise to ambiguity, confusion, even misinterpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4381350/21813).