# How do I symbolically express a statement of the form "Something, given that something is true, will be something"?

Tags: logic, notation

I am focusing especially on the "something, given that something is true" part.

An example would be "An equation in the form $ax^2$ given that $a \ne 0$ will have a derivative greater than $0$."

Instead of saying "$ax^2$ given that $a \ne 0$", can I instead say one of the below?

1. "$ax^2$ | $a \ne 0$"
2. "$ax^2$ : $a \ne 0$"
3. "$ax^2 \ni a \ne 0$"

If not, what would be the right way of saying it? If more than one are right, then what makes them different? Or, instead of using symbols, should I just stick with natural language instead?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Your example is problematic, because $ax^2$ is not an equation. Equations have an **equa**ls sign

Comment: Anyway, I agree with Ted's answer, don't use symbolic language unless you are specifically trying to learn the precision of the formal language, or you are working on a blackboard in a lecture. The only place the symbol "such that" should be used is on a blackboard - it is not a formal symbol.

Comment: In any event, none of these are valid use of standard formal languages.

Comment: Alright, I'll denote it as an expression from now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to use natural language instead of symbols here. The suggestions 1 through 3 above are not standard notation at all. In fact, "given" sounds quite awkward in this context and I would replace it with "if", for example, "If $a \ne 0$, an equation in the form $ax^2$..."

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do that from now on. On a related note, if there are multiple conditions, then should I use "and" or "$\land$"? For example "$b > 0$ $\land$ $b \ne \infty$" or "$b > 0$ and $b \ne \infty$"?

Comment: You should write "and", not $\land$. In general, do not use symbols for logical connectives like "if", "and", etc. Use words.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of saying "$ax^2$ given that $a \ne 0$", can I instead say
>
> 1. $ax^2$ | $a \ne 0$ $\quad ax^2$ will have a derivative greater than $0.$
> 2. $ax^2$ : $a \ne 0$ $\quad ax^2$ will have a derivative greater than $0.$
> 3. $ax^2 \ni a \ne 0$ $\quad ax^2$ will have a derivative greater than $0.$
>
> If more than one are right, then what makes them different?

Your three symbols all literally read as *such that* (observe that its logical meaning varies with context: “for each $x$ *such that* $P(x)$ is true, $Q(x)$ is also true” is a conditional (‘if’ statement), whereas “$P(x)$ is true *such that* $Q(x)$ is true” is a conjunction (‘and’ statement)).

Among the three symbols, only `|` and `:` are common (by the way, `∋` also means “contains the element”). Generally, because peppering mathematical prose with symbols decreases readability, the phrase *such that* should be spelt out, or abbreviated as “s.t.”, except in set notation in which case either of the first two symbols is fine. In fact, writing `:` in formal sentences [can lead to mistranslation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4381350/21813) including when it's not clear whether the symbol is functioning as a delimiter.

*Given that*, on the other hand, usually means ‘if’, like in “*Given that* $a\ne0,\;ax^2$ has a derivative greater than $0.$”